# Softlayer API to get updates on a ticket

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get updates of a ticket using rest API. I have the ticket ID and I am trying to use

```
GET: https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Ticket/26374877/getObject?objectMask=updates
```

But this does not give me the updates of the ticket. Anything wrong with the API usage?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the updates using this:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/26372051/getObject?objectMask=mask[updates]
```

make sure your ticket have updates.

Regards

Comment: I do get updates but there are lots of entries like                                                                              {
        "key": "SE_9",
        "keyName": "SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_MANAGE",
        "name": "Manage Certificates (SSL)"
      }

Comment: so Do you want only to see the updates and get rid of the other entries?

Comment: Only updates you can get that using the method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/getUpdates using mask you cannot get rid of all data, but you can reduce them , try this mask objectMask=mask[id,updates]

Comment: Updates is not a datatype.                                                                                                                  https://{{sluser}}:{{slkey}}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Ticket/26374877/getUpdates?objectMask=mask[id,entry] worked for me :) Thanks